# Finding the least loaded server

Tags: algorithm, load-balancing

Given three servers which A , B , C in which A can handle 50% of the traffic , B can handle 30% of the traffic and C can handle 20% of the traffic come up with a formula to distribute load efficiently. The current load of the servers is also an input to the function.

I could not come up with the "formula" he is asking for. Is there any specific answer to this question ?

Comment: I seem to recall this question being asked a few months ago on SO.  Might have been migrated to ServerFault.  I was always curious what the answer was.

Comment: The title of this question is called "finding the least loaded server", but the text implies coming up with a load-balancing algorithm?  In any case, if the current load is an input to the equation, then why isn't the answer, "pick the least loaded server".  Do load and traffic not mean the same thing?

Comment: I'm assuming you calculate each servers current load using the number of network connections/traffic, then route new connections to the server with the smallest load?

Answer (score 5):

There are a few different ways to distribute load that might be applicable here.

Case 1. Random assignment biased proportionally to each servers load:

```
for each request
  let x = uniformly distributed random number between 0 and 1
  if x <= 0.5
    goto A
  else if x <= 0.8
    goto B
  else
    goto C
```

Case 2. Round-Robin biased proportionally to each servers load:

```
let x = new list
push A on x 5 times
push B on x 3 times
push C on x 2 times

for each request
  y = pop x
  goto y
  push y to back of x
```

Case 3. Forget about the supposed capacity and poll for current load

```
let La = A, load of A
let Lb = B, load of B
let Lc = C, load of C

goto argmin (La,Lb,Lc)
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically, compute a relative cost to serve on each of the servers, and over some small fixed period, sum the total cost of the requests sent to said server.  Something like:

```
Cost_A = 20/50
Cost_B = 20/30
Cost_C = 20/20

Running_Total_A = 0 
Running_Total_B = 0
Running_Total_c = 0

while true: 
   If One minute has passed:
     Running_Total_A = 0 
     Running_Total_B = 0
     Running_Total_c = 0

   IF (Min(Running_Total_A,Running_Total_B,Running_Total_C) == Running_Total_A):
     Running_Total_A += Cost_A
     RouteTo(A)
   ELSE IF (Min(Running_Total_A,Running_Total_B,Running_Total_C) == Running_Total_B):
     Running_Total_B += Cost_B
     RouteTo(B)
   ELSE IF (Min(Running_Total_A,Running_Total_B,Running_Total_C) == Running_Total_C):
     Running_Total_C += Cost_C
     RouteTo(C)
```